# При попытке создать цикл сайт перестает загружаться

Tags: javascript

Изучая циклы и функции в JS, я попытался сделать цикл чтобы в консоли вёлся счет с 1 до 100 каждый 2.5 секунды. Но после моего кода сайт намертво перестал загружаться, что я не так сделал?

```
let i = 0;

while (0 < 100) {
    function iPlus() {
        i++;
        console.log(i);
    }
    setInterval(iPlus, 2500);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> сайт намертво перестал загружаться

потому что Ваш код никогда не выходит из цикла `while`. Ни один из таймеров, которые Вы создаете в этом цикле, не выполнится, пока идет цикл.

```js
let i = 0;

/*while (0 < 100)*/ {
  function iPlus() {
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    if (i == 100)
      clearInterval(timer);
  }
  let timer = setInterval(iPlus, 50);
}
```